# FFmpeg-php installation error on CentOS 6 64x bit

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, centos6, ffmpeg-php

I am trying to install ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php. FFMpeg installed perfectly.when i am trying to install ffmpeg-php. When i ran command for **./configure** it configuare fine. when i ran command **make** its give me below error. I tried all the way at last i am facing this error.

`make: *** [ffmpeg_movie.lo] Error 1`

**OS:  CENTOS 6.4 x86_64 virtuozzo – vps**

Please, give me any suggestion or help to solve this error.

Thanks In advance..!!

Comment: This might be better asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or on serverfault.stackexchange.com.  Its not really programming related, even though you are asking about the PHP library.

Comment: @fullybaked : Thank you. I was not aware about that before . Thanks Again. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226157/how-to-setup-ffmpeg-for-centos-release-6-5-server